# How to count values in collection?

Tags: sql, meteor

Please anyone can help me? I want to calculate the collection in meteor but I don't know the code. I want the code like this code in sql 
`"SELECT category,COUNT(category) FROM table GROUP BY category);') "` and this code

```
" SELECT unit,category,COUNT(category)  
FROM table where unit like "%'.$searchtype.'%" GROUP BY unit, category;')"
```

Please I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

this is a syntax error the group function can not work with the single
example:

`select DEPTNO,COUNT(EMPNO),SUM(SAL) form emp  GROUP BY DEPTNO`

the above statement is work fine because we select the DEPTNO and GROUP BY DEPTNO

BUT if we select like this
    select **ENAME** ,COUNT(EMPNO),SUM(SAL) form emp  GROUP BY DEPTNO
this is syntax error as I mentioned above which group function can not work with a single
I hope I understand what did U mean. and my answer  is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count()` method of a cursor, see [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/count).

```
Collection.find({...}).count();
```

Comment: I did the coding like this but its not function.                                                                 Template.count_status.helpers({
profile: function(){
    return Profile.find({status: 'Available',
  category: { $in: ['NB', 'LCD'] },
}).count();
  }
  });